# What am I doing wrong in this while loop with dates?

Tags: php

Why are the dates in the while loop not incrementing properly?  (See the code comments)
Any ideas?

```
$d1 = strtotime($row['quote_valid_from']);
$d2 = strtotime($row['quote_valid_until']);
$min_date = min($d1, $d2);
//echo date('Y-m-d', $min_date).'<br>';  //(2012-01-01 - start of contract) 
$max_date = max($d1, $d2);           
//echo date('Y-m-d', $max_date).'<br>'; //(2014-12-31 end of contract)  
$ia = 0;  // set counter to 0
$nextdate = '';  // set next invoice date to 0
$prevdate = '';  // set previous invoice date to 0
while ($min_date <= $max_date) 
{
$nextdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['quote_valid_from'] . ' +'.$ia.' MONTHS'));  // start at 0 and increment at end of insert statement
$prevdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nextdate . ' -1 MONTHS')); // for the previous invoice date, just decuct one month from the next invoice date
echo $prevdate.'<br>';  
echo $nextdate.'<br>';
// Here is the weird thing:  
// The latest date I get in my while loop is:  2012-08-01
// Insert happens now.
$ia++;  //increment $ia by 1
$min_date = strtotime('+'.$ia.' MONTHS', $min_date);  //add a month on to my minumum date for the while
} // end while
```

Thanks
J

Comment: Define "one month". 31 days? 30? 28? ... 29?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using DateTime for this. Much cleaner. This code requires PHP 5.5:

```
$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2012-01-01');
$end   = new DateTimeImmutable('2014-12-31');
while($start <= $end) {
    $nextdate = $start->modify('+1 month');
    $prevdate = $start->modify('-1 month');
    echo $prevdate->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';  
    echo $nextdate->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
    $start    = $nextdate;
}
```

Other points:

- Your min/max concept is unnecessary. Your start date should always be before your end date. if it's not, you have a massive issue with your software.

**For PHP 5.5.3 or older**

```
$start = new DateTime('2012-01-01');
$end   = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
while($start <= $end) {
    $nextdate = clone $start;
    $nextdate->modify('+1 month');
    $prevdate = clone $start;
    $prevdate->modify('-1 month');
    echo $prevdate->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';  
    echo $nextdate->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
    $start = $nextdate;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct?  The problem is that $start and $end does not seem to be comparable variables, but instances of a class, so the while loop never gets entered into?  Any ideas?

Comment: DateTime and its related classes are comparable. It's one of the reasons it is so powerful. [Here's a fiddle that shows it working](http://3v4l.org/0Cakv).

Comment: It seems that it does not work in 5.5.3 or lower only from 5.5.4 upwards.

Comment: Must have been a bug in the early versions of PHP5.5. But it is possible to rewrite this using normal DateTime classes. DateTimeImmutable just made it a little simpler. I added an untested snippet that *should* work in previous versions of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are incrementing `$min_date` exponentially by incrementing `$ia` and then adding that to `$min_date`, you just want to add one month to `$min_date` for each iteration. ie:

```
$min_date = strtotime('+1 MONTHS', $min_date);
```